# Randomly Generate 4 digit Code & Check if exist, Then re-generate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My code randomly generates a 4 or 5 digit code along with 3 digit pre-defined text and checks in database, If it is already exists, then it regenerates the code and saves into database.

But sometimes the queries get stuck & become slower, if each pre-defined keyword has around 1000 record.

Lets take an example for one `Keyword "XYZ"` and `Deal ID = 100` and lets say it has 8000 records in database. The do while loops take a lot of time.

```
$keyword = "XYZ"; // It is unique for each deal id.
dealID = 100; // It is Foreign key of another table.
$initialLimit = 1;
$maxLimit = 9999;

do {
    $randomNo = rand($initialLimit, $maxLimit);
    $coupon = $keyword . str_pad($randomNo, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $findRecord = DB::table('codes')
        ->where('code', $coupon)
        ->where('deal_id', $dealID)
        ->exists();

    } while ($findRecord == 1);
```

As soon as the do-while loops end, Record is being inserted into database after above code. But the Above code takes too much time,

The above query is printed as follow in MySQL. like for above example deal id, it has already over 8000 records. The above code keeps querying until it finds. When traffic is high, app becomes slower.

```
select exists(select * from `codes` where `code` = 'XYZ1952' and `deal_id` = '100');
select exists(select * from `codes` where `code` = 'XYZ2562' and `deal_id` = '100');
select exists(select * from `codes` where `code` = 'XYZ7159' and `deal_id` = '100');
```

Multiple queries like this get stuck in database. The codes table has around 500,000 records against multiple deal ids. But Each deal id has around less than 10,000 records, only few has more than 10,000.

Any suggestions, How can I improve the above code?

Or I should use the MAX() function and find the code and do the +1 and insert into db?

Comment: the woos of doing it in the same request, eventually your run out of codes and it will timeout.. a better way would be to move all current codes into a new table and mark them as taken, then precompute a bunch more codes in a side task and mark them as not taken, then when you need  a new free code, simply pick a random one which is not taken. Or dont use random XYZ0000-XYZ9999 but instead XYZ<database unique row id>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When 80% of the numbers are taken, it takes time to find one that is not taken.  The first test loses 80% of the time; the second loses 64% of the time, then 51%, etc.  Once in a while, it will take a hundred tries to find a free number.  And if the random number generator is "poor", it could literally never finish.

Let's make a very efficient way to generate the numbers.

Instead of looking for a free one, pre-determine all 9999 values.  Do this by taking all the numbers 1..9999 and shuffle them.  Store that list somewhere and "pick the next one" (instead of scrounging for an unused one).

This could be done with an extra column (indexed).  Or an extra table.  Or any number of other ways.